# How to set Excel 2010 default workbook calculation as manual?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

In Excel, the workbook calculation of formula is attached to each file, set by 
File -> Options -> Formulas -> Calculation options -> Workbook Calculation.

However, if Excel is opened directly, not by opening a file, a "Book1" will be opened and the setting is always "automatic". How could I make the default setting "manual"?

I found [these instructions](http://www.techsupportforum.com/forums/f57/how-do-i-change-the-default-settings-of-excel-552736.html) below:

> Changing the default is done in the following way:
>
> Create a new Excel document in which all default settings are set e.g.
>   fonts, styles, logo, header, footer, ...
>
> Save the file as book.xlt in the excel system startup folder
>   File > Save as
>   Browse to the Excel system startup folder
>   File name : book
>   Save as : Template (*.xlt)
>
> Note:Excel searches the following directories to open all files in it
>   when it is started
>
> 'User Excel Startup Folder'
>   c:\winnt\Profiles\\Application
>   Data\Microsoft\excel\xlstart
>  c:\Documents and
>   Settings\\Application Data\Microsoft\excel\xlstart
>   'System Excel Startup Folder'
>  c:\Program Files\Microsoft
>   Office\office\xlstart
>  'Alternate Startup Folder'

However it seems it's talking about Windows NT. My OS is Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do as Sir Adelaide states above, in [his answer](https://superuser.com/q/1138597/150988#1138616), but try saving the new workbook as `book.xltx` (or `.xltm` if you want to include macros) in the `XLStart` folder. Restart Excel and see if it does what you want it to do.

The `XLSTART` folder should be in a location similar to this for 2010: `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART`

Where: *`<username>`* is the name of your profile on the machine.

Comment: Excellent. Glad you're up and running.

Answer (score 0):

Open a new blank workbook.

Change the setting to manual calculation.

Save As, select file type "Excel Template (*.xltx)". This will change your explorer location to somewhere near where we want to be.

Don't save yet, but in the 'breadcrumbs' at the top of the Save As explorer window click on 'Microsoft', then browse into the folder 'Excel>XLSTART'. You'll be somewhere like "C:\Users\Athos\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART"

Now you are in the right spot, but don't save yet. Change the file type back to "Excel Workbook (*.xlsx)" and save with any file name.

Comment: it doesn't work on my PC.

Comment: Ok, well I came up with those instructions using a Win 7 Excel 2010 computer. Worked for me. Is there anything else in the AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART folder? Mine was empty but forseeably other spreadsheets there could provide other defaults.